# Regex Substitution: only replace the first occurance from a "or" condition

Tags: regex, pcre, substitution

I need to replace `\d+` and `a+` to `x`, I want to replace all the `\d+` to `x`, but for `a+`, I only want to replace the first occurance if there's any.

Is it possible to use only one regex to achieve this?

| Input | Desired Output |
| --- | --- |
| `123,456,789` | `x,x,x` |
| `123,456,a,789` | `x,x,x,x` |
| `aaa,aa,aaa` | `x,aa,aaa` |
| `aa,123,456,aaaa,789` | `x,x,x,aaaa,x` |
| `aaa,123,456,aa,789,aaaa` | `x,x,x,aa,x,aaaa` |

[This](https://regex101.com/r/P4EbWL/1) sure does not work:

```
/\d+|a+/gm
```

I'm using PCRE regex engine, or is there any mode modifier or control verb can do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you probably don't want to do it with one regex anyway, this is not code golf.

Comment: @user202729 Well, this is awkward... I’m doing a regex quiz and the answer must be a single regex... Kinda stuck at this one for a long time :/

Comment: Then it's not a practical problem...

Comment: (but for the answer, probably lookbehind)

Comment: Unfortunately, there's  [Asking a quiz question - Is it OK? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340861/asking-a-quiz-question-is-it-ok) (tl;dr; it's not, unless it happens to be somewhat useful in real life too) (I guess the linked question there got down voted because of the meta effect, and as a result the author deletes it) (so I don't feel like posting an answer because of that...)

Comment: @user202729 This is actually a simplified version of my problem. The real question is to shorten a ipv6 using regex. `1:0:0:0:2:0:0:3` should be shortened into `1::2:0:0:3` instead of `1::2::3`. Basically I’m stuck at this step.

Comment: @HaoWu Oh, better ask this directly then, solutions might be different/easier, having the context usually helps.

Comment: Because the length of an IPV6 has an upper limit. // Is variable-length lookbehind supported?

Comment: @user202729 PCRE does not support unknown length lookbehind patterns.

Comment: @sp00m The real question has too much distrctions like removing leading `0`s and shorten `0000:0001` to `0:1` etc which I'm already handled. My original intent is to focus on the step that I don't know how to get my hands on.

Comment: Not really variable-length, but `(?<!a.{,40})`?

Comment: Not really related to the question, but is the quiz available online?

Comment: Why not replace all `\d+` globally, then replace all `a+` non-globally (ie once)?

Comment: @Bohemian Op mentioned that they're doing some sort of puzzle...

Comment: Infinite-width lookbehinds in PCRE can be achieved with callouts that require some code implementation. You can't solve the problem you asked in the question without some extra code. Thus, Bohemian's suggestion (it was actually my first thought when seeing the question) is what we would use in practice. Changing `1:0:0:0:2:0:0:3` into `1::2:0:0:3` is [easy](https://regex101.com/r/pOCiPi/2) with `^(.*?)\b0(?::0)*\b` / `$1`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's not just about removing consecutive `0:`s, but using a single regex to shorten any given ipv6 address correctly. It's actually a [regex101 quiz](https://regex101.com/quiz/27). So it's quite impossible to replace it without a `g` flag

Comment: If everything fails, you can still list all the possible ways and replace it with the groups. That would only be possible if the length is fixed however.

Comment: For achieve this goal we can imagine some recursion: ``\d+|((?<!a|(?!(?1)).))a+``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I forget that answer must be posted aside and post it in comments at first.

Now here it is:

Regex: `\d+|((?<!a|(?!(?1)).))a+`

Replacement: `x`

https://regex101.com/r/v24o7B/1

Answer (score 1):

After a serious struggle, I came up with this idea:

```
(?:(\G|^)|)(?(1)(?:a+|\d+([^a\d]+))|\d+)
```

Replace with

```
x$2
```

- `(?:(\G|^)|)`

> Testing last anchor `\G` or the start of the string `^` before every match optionally, and put the caught anchor in group 1

- `(?(1)(?:a+|\d+([^a\d]+))|\d+)`

> - If cause, if the anchor has been detected, matching `a+` or `\d+`
> - If the sequence detected is `\d+`, also matches the `([^a\d]+)` to keep the anchor for next match.
> - If the sequence detected is `a+`, only matches `a+`, so the anchor will be broken for the next test.
> - While the anchor `\G` is not detected in group 1, that means `a+` has already been detected, after that only matches `\d+`, and the `\G` will never be detected anymore.

Here's the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/xrNfqy/1)

It seems it is only useful in this scenario, not sure if it's useful for the real question, though.

Comment: Nice idea to use `\G` to make the global replace stateful (although that's only in Perl (PCRE), you can only store one bit of memory, and people should not use this in real code anyway)

Comment: But if you can already maintain one bit, the original problem should be solvable, no?

Comment: (I suppose that perl code execution is not available?)

Comment: @user202729 Because it doesn't work if the `a+` and `\d+` are consecutive, so it's quite hard to adapt this concept to the real problem. But this concept could be useful for some situations.

Comment: If it isn't consecutive, just use a trick similar to your `\2`, no?

Comment: While you can use `(\G|^)?` instead of `(?:(\G|^)|)`, you can do even better and use `(?(?=\G|^)` as your conditional in the first place (obviously you then substitute `x$1` instead).

Comment: @Neil Yes you're right, and it could be [`(?(?=\G|^)(?:a+|\d+([^a\d]+))|\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/b8OfYz/1)

Comment: You can rewrite it like that: https://regex101.com/r/xrNfqy/2